# Logic operators on Structures in C

Tags: c, if-statement, struct, logic

Suppose I have two different structures, Struct1 and Struct2. They both have different elements in them.
What happens if I compare them like this:

```
if((Struct1) && (Struct2))
{
    doSomething();
}
```

I just found some code with this logic and was wondering what was happening.
Thanks!

**EDIT:** Struct1 and Struct2 are both pointers to two different structures, not structures themselves.

Comment: It would be helpful to know the exact type for `Struct1` and `Struct2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that to work, you must have pointers, not structures.  That is, the code might be:

```
void somefunc(struct structA *Struct1, struct structB *Struct2)
{
    if (Struct1 && Struct2)
    {
        doSomething(Struct1, Struct2);
    }
}
```

This checks that neither of the pointers is NULL before using them.  You cannot compare structures directly, so if the code were:

```
void somefunc(struct structA Struct1, struct structB Struct2)
{
    if (Struct1 && Struct2)
    {
        doSomething(Struct1, Struct2);
    }
}
```

you would have a semantic error; you simply cannot compare whole structures with anything.

The capitalization of the variables is aconventional.

Answer (score 5):

Using a structure in an `if` is illegal syntax for C - it won't be accepted by a conforming compiler. Put another way: you can't use a structure in a boolean context.

Most likely in your code - if it *is* true code - `Struct1` aren't structures but (possibly) pointers or something else. In that case the if will be taken if both are non-NULL.

Comment: No wonder I was having a problem figuring out how it performs the boolean conversion :-P

Comment: Thanks, upon looking at my code further, they were both pointers to structures.

Answer (score 4):

There's two possibilities here:

**This will check if st1 and st2 are both not pointing to NULL:**

```
struct Struct1 *st1 = ...;
struct Struct2 *st2 = ...;

if (st1 && st2) {
    ...
}
```

**This is invalid code:**

```
struct Struct1 st1 = ...;
struct Struct2 st2 = ...;

if (st1 && st2) {
    ...
}
```

**Note that this is also invalid code:**

```
struct Struct1 st1 = ...;

if (st1) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It'll return "true" or 1 if all the sub-fields are identical else it'll return "false" or 0.

Its the basic concept of these conditional operators.

For more information about && operators visit [Here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/logande.htm)

Thanks.

Comment: `The && (logical AND) operator indicates whether both operands are true.` the link you gave says nothing about comparing sub-fields... also notice the question says that the `Struct1` and `Struct2` are pointers...